# What is the domains folder used for in Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, glassfish-3

I was getting inside the folders of Glassfish, I found a folder named domains and inside it I found domain1.

My questions are:

- what is **domains** and what is it used for?

seeing the folder **domain1** make me understand that we can have domaine2, domaine3 and so on

- what is the rule, do we have to have many domains?
- when should we create another domain folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain in GlassFish is basically a set of configurations that are used together in a single environment. Usually, you would need a single domain folder and it's safe to use the stock `domain1`. Inside a domain you can define multiple isntances and even multiple clusters so you don't need to have more than one domain at a time.

More domains are useful when you want to switch between different configurations frequently, or as templates for varioius environments. You could have a `development` domain, `test` domain, `production` domain, each tuned for specific environments.

For example, [Payara Server](https://www.payara.fish/), which is derived from GlassFish, adds additional `payaradomain`, which is tuned for production, while the default `domain1` is tuned for development as it's in GlassFish. Therefore you may easily choose  the best default configuration for your needs just by switching the domain when you start the server.

Another usecase would be if you develop 2 or more unrelated applications and you want to keep them separate in the server. Then you would create a separate domain for each of them and run GlassFish with the appropriate domain so that the applications are isolated. The second domain can be configured to a different set of ports so that the servers don't collide.

Comment: having these 3 domains `development, test and production` seems as a best practice is it the case?

Comment: Yes, I would say it's best practise to have a separate configuration for development, test and production. However, they don't need to be present in the same GlassFish/Payara installation. Alternatively, you can have 3 different installations of GlassFish and always use domain1 with different configuration, it's up to you whether having multiple configuration domains is convenient.

Comment: can you please tell how can we work with different domains technically (in netbeans and glassfish)? any link that explains this?

Comment: In Netbeans, you simply specify the name of the domain when you add a new server instead of the default `domain1`. For each domain you need a separate server configuration (add new server). Here's [a detailed guide](http://blog.payara.fish/adding-payara-server-to-netbeans) If you want to start from command line, just add the domain name as a parameter ot the `asadmin start-domain` command

Comment: thank you for the valuable information, I make your answer a correct one  =) . But I still need one more information if you can be "more" kind, I've created a new domain in glassfish server interface, but the folder of the new domain was not created in the domains folder, how is it possible to create a new domain (ofcourse not in the CMD but in a UI, netbeans or glassfish server)

Comment: The only way to create a new domain is using the command line as I described. If you create a domain using the UI, it's a different thing. You maybe created a new instance or a new virtual server bound to a HTTP domain. But there's no way to create a new domain in UI because UI only modifies the current domain of the running server.

Comment: Using Netbeans, you can create a new domain in UI. You have to "Add Server...", even if you already added Payara before. Continue to add Payara Server again, but in the **Domain location** dialog, type in the name of a new domain in the **Domain** field instead of selecting an existing one. Netbeans will create a new domain and use it with this server configuration.